# Do Constructor methods get executed by JVM while instantiating the Objects during runtime? If not so, then why?

Tags: java

I have a typical scenario in java where I am confused about Constructors.

For Example,
1. If Java creates the Instance of the Object during runtime for the Class which has a main method.(Ref : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/jvm-create-object-main-class-class-contains-main/)

```
public class TestJava {    
    TestJava(){
        System.out.println("CONSTRUCTOR CALL");
    }

    static void staticOutput(){
        System.out.println("STATIC METHOD CALL");
    }

    public static  void main(String args[]){
        //TestJava javaClass=new TestJava();

    }
}
```

Here, the javaClass is an object that is instantiated(Commented). On running the Program, I see no constructor/static methods being executed. But on removing the comment and running the program, the Constructor class is executed. If the JVM creates the instance of the Class for which it has a main(), why does the constructor does not get executed while we use the main() as the constructor must be executed when Object is instantiated.

Comment: main() is a static method bind with class. JVM does not need to instantiate a new object to execute main().

Answer (score 1):

The "entry point" for any Java application is the `public static void main()` method. The Java application cannot start at all without first calling that method.

Since the `main()` method is `static`, it is called **without** needing to instantiate the `TestJava` class or call its constructor.